# Windows 10 System Restore - Old restore points not appearing in System Restore

Tags: windows, windows-10, restore, system-restore

I've been facing multiple issues with Windows 10 not starting or not logging in lately. Eventually I had to run the system reset from the recovery environment, which claims to keep personal files intact while deleting all applications and system settings, and that's exactly what it did.

Upon inspection of the System Volume Information folders on both hard drives, the recovery points from before the reset were still there (8GB or so in size, with names like {66c05d6f-85c1-11e6-9512-448500442b6c}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752} and dates that I recognize as dates from the old restore points). However, the System Restore menu only shows restore points that were created after the reset. (I'm aware there is a checkbox that hides some restore points by default, but that is not the issue.) Oddly enough, these old restore points also contribute to the "total" amount of disk space used by restore points, despite Windows not recognizing them.

Here's my question: **Is there any way (via a 3rd party application or some clever workaround) to get Windows to recognize these hidden restore points or otherwise apply them to the system?** Is it possible, for example, to "trick" System Restore by substituting the data from an old restore point into the new restore point file?

I've looked at multiple third-party applications that claim to work with system restore, but some are out of date and incompatible and the rest of them (at least the ones I tried) only show the restore points recognized by the system. I've tried System Restore Manager, System Restore Explorer, and SysRestore with no luck.

I'm beginning to get the impression that it's not possible to retrieve these old restore points, but I figured there may be someone out there who knows more about system restore files than I do.

Comment: Why do you want to use system restore points from before your system was fixed?  You would just introduce the problems to your new installation?  The Reset feature reinstalls Windows, it moves our files around, to hide that fact.

Comment: I have restore points from before my system started crashing, and I'm pretty sure the crashes were triggered by something I did since then. The only reason I used reset instead of restore was because system restore wasn't running correctly either.